# Unable to write to a file till some specific line

Tags: java, inputstream, filereader, outputstream

I am trying to split files from one file to 4 different files. So I am dividing the file by some "x" value and wanna write the file till that value and from there to next file continues till the file contents ends.

I am checking some x value in the file using buffer reader and checking with the content is equal to the x value and do the splitting.

Splitting is coming but in some another way, like it's reading the file and writing till the line number which is "x". But I need all the lines till that "x" value is present in the file.

I have a time in the file like start time hh:mm:ss and I am checking this with the hh:mm:ss with my x value and do the splitting like below

```
// inputs to the below method
//  filePath = "//somepath";
// splitlen = 30;
// name ="somename"; */

public void split(String FilePath, long splitlen, String name) {
        long leninfile = 0, leng = 0;
        int count = 1, data;
        try {
            File filename = new File(FilePath);
            InputStream infile = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
            data = infile.read();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(infile));

            while (data != -1) {
                filename = new File("/Users//Documents/mysrt/" + count + ".srt");
                OutputStream outfile = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
                String strLine = br.readLine();
                String[] atoms = strLine.split(" --> ");

                if (atoms.length == 1) {
//                   outfile.write(Integer.parseInt(strLine + "\n"));

                }
                else {

                    String startTS = atoms[0];
                    String endTS = atoms[1];
                    System.out.println(startTS + "\n");
                    System.out.println(endTS + "\n");
                    String startTime = startTS.replace(",", ".");
                    String endTime = endTS.replace(",", ".");
                    System.out.println("startTime" + "\n" + startTime);
                    System.out.println("endTime" + "\n" + endTime);
                    String [] arrOfStr = endTime.split(":");

                    System.out.println("=====arrOfStr=====");
                    int x = Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr[1]);
                    System.out.println(arrOfStr[1]);
                    System.out.println("===x repeat==");
                    System.out.println(x);
                    System.out.println("===splitlen repeat==");
                    System.out.println(splitlen);
                    System.out.println(data);
                    System.out.println(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println(br.read());

                    while (data != -1 && x < splitlen) {
                       outfile.write(br.readLine().getBytes());

                        data = infile.read();
                            x++;
                    }

                    System.out.println("===== out of while x =====");
                    System.out.println(br.readLine());
                    System.out.println(x);

                    leninfile += leng;
                    leng = 0;
                    outfile.close();
                    firstPage = false;
                    firstPage = true;
                    count++;
                    splitlen = splitlen + 30;
                    System.out.println("=====splitlen after=====" +splitlen);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am incrementing the time with some number to read the next lines in file and with into another file.

Here splitlen is 30 , so it's writing the data till 30 lines in a new file. Then it's incrementing splitlen+30 i.e 60. But, it's reading next 60 lines and writing into next file.

But I need to check this splitlen with the time provided in the content of file and I should split that line.

Please suggest me where I am doing wrong. If you provide snippet it will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I didn’t really understand your question but I want to point out that every time you do `System.out.println(br.readLine());` you are reading a line from the file without handling the read line.

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson I hope you know how the .srt subtitle file will be. My actual need is to read each line of a file and then I am checking with the x value with the endTime in the line. So if my x value is 30, I will check with all lines line by line and will stop reading where ever it is matching and write to a new file till that line which satisfied with my x value but in the above code it's writing in a new file till 30 lines in the file which is not I am I am looking for

Comment: Ok but as I wrote in my previous comment, you're skipping some lines in the file you're reading from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
public void split(String filePath, long splitLen, String name) {
    File fileSource = new File(filePath);
    int count = 0;
    boolean endOfFile = false;
    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    int hour = 0; // an accumulator for hours
    int min = 0; // an accumulator for minutes
    int sec = (int) splitLen; // an accumulator for seconds
    int _hour = 0; // hours from the file
    int _min = 0; // minutes from the file
    int _sec = 0; // seconds from the file
    try (   // try with resources to close files automatically
            FileReader frSource = new FileReader(fileSource);
            BufferedReader buffSource = new BufferedReader(frSource);
            ) {
        String strIn = null;
        while(!endOfFile) {
            File fileOut = new File("f:\\test\\mysrt\\" + count + ".srt");
            try (   // try with resources to close files automatically
                    FileWriter fwOut = new FileWriter(fileOut);
                    ) {
                if (strIn != null) {
                    // write out the last line read to the new file
                    fwOut.write(strIn + lineSeparator);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < splitLen; i++) {
                    strIn = buffSource.readLine();
                    if (strIn == null) {
                        endOfFile = true; // stop the while loop
                        break; // exit the for loop
                    }
                    if (strIn.indexOf("-->") > 0) {
                        String endTime = strIn.split("-->")[1];
                        _hour = extractHours(endTime); // get the hours from the file
                        _min = extractMinutes(endTime); // get the minutes from the file
                        _sec = extractSeconds(endTime); // get the seconds from the file
                        if (_hour >= hour && _min >= min && _sec >= sec) { // if the file time is greater than our accumulators
                            sec += splitLen; // increment our accumulator seconds
                            if (sec >= 60) { // if accumulator seconds is greater than 59, we need to convert it to minutes and seconds
                                min += sec / 60;
                                sec = sec % 60;
                            }
                            if (min >= 60) { if accumulator minutes is greater than 59, we need to convert it to hours and minutes
                                hour += min / 60;
                                min = min % 60;
                            }
                            break; // break out of the for loop, which cause the file to be completed and a new file started.
                        }
                    }
                    fwOut.write(strIn + lineSeparator); // write out to the new file
                }
                fwOut.flush();
            }
            count++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private int extractMinutes(String time) {
    // You need to implement this, I don't know the format of your time
    return 0;
}

private int extractSeconds(String time) {
    // You need to implement this, I don't know the format of your time
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is Not I am looking for.It should not split after each 30 lines. This is also splitting file after 30 lines .. I need to check the 00:30:44 this 30 which is in the lines. I have to compare the splitlen with the content in each line. if it satisfies it should split till that line

Comment: Adjust the `for` loop to suit your needs. You could change it to a `while(true)` and just `break;` out when you need to split

Comment: Till that I too achieved .. but reading a line to compare with my splitlen I an unable to get

Comment: So, if I understand you, the 30 is a measure of minutes, not a line counter, and your input file has lines in it with timestamps. and you want to break the input file into several smaller files that contain up to 30 minutes of lines from the input file. Is that correct?

Comment: I have updated the code with that in mind. You will need to implement the parsing of the hours, minutes and seconds from the time.

Comment: Yup sure. I will check that parsing .. Will check your code and let you know if I stuck any where.. thanks a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177030/discussion-between-user6250770-and-bcr666).

Comment: As I am having time like 00:00:04,074 this format. I am doing , String [] arrOfStr = endTime.split(":"); 
_min = arrOfStr[1];
_hour = arrOfStr[0];
I don't need to check with the seconds.. only minutes and hours is enough
But still it's writing till 30 lines rather than to check for 30 minutes in the line :( and almost 287 files were creating :(

Comment: Hi, Even I have to subtract seconds also.  If we have 125/4 = it's coming 31.25 .. this means 31 minutes and (0.25*60) = 15 seconds
need to subtract the seconds also from time stamp. I am trying but negative values or zero values appearing :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the timestamp you're looking at is in HH:MM:ss but with the `splitlen` and `x` variables you are only working with minutes.

So you need to keep track of both hours and minutes, maybe this could be done with some DateTime class but here is a simple int solution

```
//somewhere at the top 
int hour = 0;
int minutes = 30;

//where you today increase splitlen
minutes += 30;
if (minutes == 60) {
   hour++;
   minutes = 0;
}

//parse also hours
int y = Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr[0]);
int x = Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr[1]);

//you need to rewrite this to compare x and y against hour and minutes
while (data != -1 && x < splitlen) {
```

So now you will not be looking for 30, 60, 90,... minutes but instead 00:30, 01:00, 01:30 and so on. Of course you must also be prepared to handle the situation where there is no entry for a whole minute unless of course you already do so.

`checkTime` is of course a a key method here and it might be a good idea to make the last hour and minute when the file was split into class members but they could of course also be sent as parameters from `split()`.

**Update**

Here is a simplified version of the `split` method to give an example on how to solve this, it is not complete but should be a good starting point for solving the issue. I try to make use of how a `.str` file is constructed and make use of the logic explained above for determining when to open a new output file.

```
public void split(String filepath, long splitlen, String name) {
    int count = 1;
    try {
        File filename = new File(filepath);
        InputStream infile = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(infile));

        FileWriter outfile = createOutputFile(count);
        boolean isEndOfFile = false;
        while (!isEndOfFile) {

            String line = null;
            int i = 1;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                outfile.write(line);

                if (line.trim().isEmpty()) { //last line of group
                    i = 1;
                    continue;
                }

                if (i == 2) { //Timestamp row
                    String[] split = line.split("-->");
                    if (checkTime(split)) {
                        count++;
                        outfile.flush();
                        outfile.close();
                        outfile = createOutputFile(count);
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private FileWriter createOutputFile(int index) {
    //Create new outputfile and writer 
    return null; 
}

private boolean checkTime(String[] arr) {
    //use start or end time in arr to check if an even half or full hour has been passed
    return true;
}
```

Comment: yes, this is what I need. But stuck how to read a line and compare and write to the new file. Now I am only writing upto 30 lines , 60 lines and 90 lines e.t.c . But I need to write the file when the line have 30 minutes, 60 minutes and 90 minutes and so on. Please suggest me how can I achieve that

Comment: But that’s what my answer is about.

Comment: you shown me to check the comparison but unable to write that line which line has  00:30:23 . It's writing till 30 line number in file

Comment: @user6250770 I added a simplified version of `split()` to my answer.